# creating multiple directories

Tags: python, directory, mkdir

I am trying to create multiple subdirectories and move files into those subdirectories, name the subdirectory the number of which loop it is on, this is what i have:

```
for x in range(1,20):
     os.makedirs('{}/'.format(replace)+str(x)+'/')
     shutil.move(filename,'{}/'.format(replace)+str(x)+'/')
     shutil.move(filename1,'{}/'.format(replace)+str(x)+'/')
```

I am getting this error:

```
 File "testdraft.py", line 285, in findReplace
    shutil.move(f, '{}/'.format(replace)+str(x)+'/')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 284, in move
    if _samefile(src, dst):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 58, in _samefile
    return os.path.samefile(src, dst)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 162, in samefile
    s1 = os.stat(f1)
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, file found
```

thanks for any help

Comment: Please show us what `f` is—either print out its `repr`, or show the code that generates it, or, ideally, both. Otherwise, this is not a [complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help.mcve), and can only be answered by guessing.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably your `f` is a *file object*, not a filename.

You didn't actually show us any code that calls `shutil.move` with an `f`; you instead showed us code that calls it with something named `filename1`. But it doesn't matter what the name of the variable is; if what it holds if a file object that you got back from, e.g., the `open` function, you can't use it with `move`.

Hopefully, your real code is as simple as something like:

```
with open(out_path, 'w') as f:
    write_data(f)
shutil.move(f, '{}/'.format(replace)+str(x)+'/')
```

Then you just want to change the `f` in the last line to `out_path` and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your filename or filename1 variables are not actually file names, but file objects. (This is what that "file found" at the end of your error is trying to tell you.)

Additionally, you may want to consider not making the directories first:

> [shutil.move(src, dst):](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html)
>
> The destination directory must not already exist. If the destination
>   already exists but is not a directory, it may be overwritten depending
>   on os.rename() semantics.